# How to communicate between vscode extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to know how to communicate between the VS Code extensions, like one extension will publish and other extensions will subscribe.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a few ways:

- Use [commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributescommands). One extension can invoke the commands of the other extension
- Use extension APIs. For this, Extension1 returns its api from the `activate` method. Then Extension2 can get ahold of it using `extensions.extensions.getExtension('extension1.id')` and call the API using the [`.exports`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/29bead35f2a5339482158a7d48f7f0f3955629e2/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L4257) object.

In both cases, extension2 should declare that it depends on extension1 using `extensionDependencies` in its `package.json`

Comment: I am looking for something similar like this
-> sendNotification('eventName', args)
and this notification can be listen by other extensions

Comment: If you just need to talk to one extension, use commands. If you need to broadcast an event to many extensions, use an API. There is no built-in `sendNotification`

Comment: The _export_ api is the return of the _activate_ function. There is an example in the [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#extensions)